# Finding strings and then replacing them from a list

Tags: regex

Alright, I have this problem of having too many lines and too many different files to edit one by one, I need to come up with a way to do this. Regexp probably work, but I just don't know why.

I have a list like this:

```
    <a class="jTip">First</a>
    <a class="jTip">Second</a>
    <a class="jTip">Third</a>
    <a class="jTip">Fourth</a>
```

And it is a long list (around 6000 lines). There is also around 50 files with lines like this:

```
<a class="jTip">Second</a>, <a class="jTip">Fifth</a>
```

So what i want to do is to find a way to get the `<a class="jTip">First</a>` line from the list, search for it in these files, and replace it with `<a class="jTip" name="something">First</a>`.

My question is, is there a way to make regexp get lines from a list, then find and replace those lines in other files (using notepad++, but i'm open to suggestions).

**EDIT:** I think I didn't express my problem correctly. I have a long list of strings, around 6000 lines. And I have around 30 other files that includes these lines in different combinations. I need a way to do this:

Get the first line from the list file, find it in other files, replace them with a modified version of the line.
Then get the second line from the list file, find it in other files, replace them with a modified version of the line.
Then get the third line from the list file, find it in other files, replace them with a modified version of the line.

and i have to do this 6000 times (each line is different!). I cannot do it like:

find `<a class="jTip">First</a>` replace `<a class="jTip" name="something">First</a>`, because that `something` will change (I can do that manually, doesn't change very often). So for the first source/list file it will be `something` and then i'll run the same files for the second list and it will be `anything`. I cannot mass replace (I know how to replace all) `<a class="jTip">` to `<a class="jTip" name="something">`.

Sadly, i'm working on a mess of a file, so I don't even think there is a way to do this with regex. I thought I'd give it a shot.

Also, sorry for the wrong tags, I fixed it.

Lastly, is there a way to "get each (any char) from a file and replace it with (same chars) in other files" thing in regex?

Comment: do you want to do it using some JS program OR just find and replace using notepad++

Comment: I'd be okay with both, as long as it parses the list line by line and replaces everything correctly.

Comment: you can open all the files in notepad ++. hit `ctrl+h`, put `<a class="jTip">First</a>` in **Find What** field and `<a class="jTip" name="something">First</a>`  in **Replace With** field.
hit **Replace All In All Opened Documents** button.  :)

Comment: If you can use `SublimeText`, I guess it has an option to search and replace using regex

Comment: Then why has the question been tagged as Javascript, html and regex?

Comment: I already know replace all, the problem isn't that. I have to do this for first, second, third, fourth ... all the way up to 6000th line of this file and each line is named differently. So I need something that will traverse the list and find that specific line in all files, then replace.

Comment: Yup. Editors/IDEs are smart enough to do that. I search through all files most of the time in Sublime. Useful link: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_files.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `msr.exe` / `msr.gcc48` to do it with just 1 command line : extract -> search -> replace, in `tools` directory in **my open project**: https://github.com/qualiu/msr

Assume your list file is `source-list.txt`

Assume the recusive directories/files to replace are `paths-to-find` like: `dir1,dir2,file1,file2`

**Extract from list, preview 3 lines:**

`msr -p source-list.txt -it ".*<a class=\"jTip\">(\w+).*" -H 3`

**Search and replace recursively in `paths-to-find`:**

- Windows: (Use `%%a` instead of `%a` if you want save it in a file like `my.bat`/`my.cmd` to run:

  `for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('msr -p source-list.txt -it ".*<a class=\"jTip\">(\w+).*" -o "$1" -PAC') do msr -rp paths-to-find -it "(<a class=\"jTip\" name=\"something\">)\w+" -o "${1}%a" -R`
- Linux:

  `for a in $(msr -p source-list.txt -it ".*<a class=\"jTip\">(\w+).*" -o '$1' -PAC); do msr -rp paths-to-find -it "(<a class=\"jTip\" name=\"something\">)\w+" -o '${1}'$a'' -R; done`

  or

  `for a in $(msr -p source-list.txt -it '.*<a class="jTip">(\w+).*' -o '$1' -PAC); do msr -rp paths-to-find -it '(<a class="jTip" name="something">)\w+' -o '${1}'$a'' -R; done`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on a linux system, than one solution could also be using the cli programm `sed`.

```
sed -i  -e 's/<a class="jTip">First</a>/<a class="jTip" name="something">First</a>/g' {pathToFolder}/*
```

NOTE: don't forget to replace `{pathToFolder}` with your actual path

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JQuery` and achieve what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.jTip').each(function(){
     if($(this).text() === 'First' || 
     $(this).text() === 'Second' ||
     $(this).text() === 'Third'){
       $(this).attr('name','something');
       $(this).text('First');
     }
  });
})
```

```css
a[name='something']{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="jTip">First</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Second</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Third</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Fourth</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Fifth</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">First</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Second</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Third</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Fourth</a><br/>
<a class="jTip">Fifth</a>
```

To illustrate that the name `something` has been added to the element i have used a color css for it.

Comment: OP is looking to update more than 1 file(*source code*).

Comment: Then why has the question been tagged as Javascript, html and regex?

Comment: IDK. You should ask OP. This is one of those *cleaning the codebase* activity.

Comment: So I need something that will traverse the list and find that specific line in all files, then replace. I am trying to add name="something" to both First, Second and Third. I have a strange file on my hand (I didn't write this horrible mess), so the regexp or whatever i have should find `<a class="jTip">First</a><br/>` and replace it to `<a class="jTip" name="something">First</a><br/>` and then find `<a class="jTip">Second</a><br/>` and replace it to `<a class="jTip" name="something">Second</a><br/>`, so on, until the end of the list. I have around 6000 lines in the list.

Comment: Ok, i have edited my answer. You need to bring all the HTML in one single file then follow the code structure as given above.

Answer (score 0):

Open file 
press ***ctrl+f*** or ***ctrl+h*** (or go to find and replace option) type **class="jTip">** in find box and replace it with **class="jTip" name="something">**

No simpler answer will be awailable than this.